# XPath to select children specific children & parent

Tags: xml, xpath

Here is the my structure:

```
<AllCharges>
   <Charge>
     <ID>1</ID>
     <Type>A</Type>
   </Charge>
   <Charge>
     <ID>2</ID>
     <Type>A</Type>
   </Charge>
   <Charge>
     <ID>3</ID>
     <Type>B</Type>
   </Charge>
</AllCharges>
```

What I want back is the full structure but I only want results in which the Type = A.  The hard part I am finding is pulling back the parent xml nodes.  Here is an example of what my result should look like:

```
<AllCharges>
   <Charge>
     <ID>1</ID>
     <Type>A</Type>
   </Charge>
   <Charge>
     <ID>2</ID>
     <Type>A</Type>
   </Charge>
</AllCharges>
```

I would assume the XPath would look something like this but it doesn't work:
/AllCharges[//Type=A]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/AllCharges/Charge[Type='A']
```

That should do it.

The expression reads, "Select any Charge element whose parent is AllCharges, having a child element called Type whose text value is 'A'."

Tested it in the following XSLT template:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <AllCharges>
    <xsl:copy-of select="/AllCharges/Charge[Type='A']"/>
  </AllCharges>
</xsl:template>
```

The output was:

```
<AllCharges>
  <Charge>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Type>A</Type>
  </Charge>
  <Charge>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Type>A</Type>
  </Charge>
</AllCharges>
```

Comment: Hm, this is more a XSLT solution than XPath.

Answer (score 2):

xpath does not alter the XML, it just returns results within your XML document.   You can search for all 'charge' elements with type=a to get what you want.

If you want to transform the document, you'll need to look at XSL